# Java ObjectOutputStream Not Writing to ZipEntry

Tags: java, zip, outputstream, objectoutputstream

I am trying to serialize an object into a ZipEntry using an ObjectOutputStream, however it doesn't appear to be writing anything because when I print the byte array produced, it shows null. I tried writing a string with the ZipOutputStream, and upon printing the resulting byte array got a sizeable result. SO my question is: why is the objectoutput stream not correctly writing into the ZipEntry. (ConfigEntry does implement Serializable).

```
  String s = "Tired, Exhausted";
  ConfigEntry con = new ConfigEntry("rand", "random", 3);

  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try {

  ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
  ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("test.txt");
  ObjectOutputStream obs = new ObjectOutputStream(zos);

  zos.putNextEntry(entry);


  obs.writeObject(con);
  obs.close();
  zos.closeEntry();
  zos.close();


  } catch(IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace();
  }


  os = bs.getOutputStream();
  byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
  String test = new String(result, "UTF-8");
  Log.v("Mac Address", test);
  Log.v("Mac Address", Arrays.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

This `baos` goes out of scope after the `try` block. You are writing to one `baos` and you are looking into another `baos` declared in an outer scope, probably an instance member of the class.

Comment: Sorry, that was actually my bad, I meant to put the try statement after the ByteArrayOutputStream, as it is in my code. Sorry for the poor code. Edited my question.